# Why does Dash keep turning off the scopes that I use?

Tags: unity-dash

Using Ubuntu 17.04, the Dash keeps turning off the scopes that I use - it is very annoying and counterproductive.

How can I get it to stop turning off the scopes that I've enabled?

To reproduce the problem:

```
1) Open Dash
2) Type 'Vachon' (name of a Virtualbox VM)
3) Enable Virtualbox Source to get the vm to show up.
4) Close and re-open the Dash
5) Type 'Vachon'
6) Observe that the Virtualbox Source was unhelpfully turned off, and I don't get the expected search result. I have to manually turn it on again just to get the show result to show up.
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Sure, I've added exact and clear steps to reproduce the problem.